# Rails chartkick stacked bar charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using Rails [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) gem and I'm using Google charts API.

I have use this line to generate the bar chart using chartkick.

```
<%= bar_chart data, :library => {:isStacked => true} %>
```

But what i'm getting is a simple bar chart not a stacked one.My question is what is the structure of the data which i should pass to `data` parameter. I have try passing an array, like(from google charts samples)

```
[['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General','Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, '']]
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can replicate [Stacked Bar Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#StackedBars) like this:

```
data = [
  {
    name: "Fantasy & Sci Fi", 
    data: [["2010", 10], ["2020", 16], ["2030", 28]]
  },
  {
    name: "Romance", 
    data: [["2010", 24], ["2020", 22], ["2030", 19]]
  },
  {
    name: "Mystery/Crime", 
    data: [["2010", 20], ["2020", 23], ["2030", 29]]
  }
]
```

And in the template:

```
<%= bar_chart data, stacked: true %>
```

Comment: How should the query look like? My data looks something like this: `[["X1", "Y1",20],["X1","Y2",10]]` Doesn't render anything for me.