# Chartkick - Stacked vertical graph in percentage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a vertical percentage graph following the google instruction: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#StackedBars

This is how it should look like:

[image: Good final graph]

However, this is how it look right now.
[image: Wrong one]

I am using the same `data` as the one of google.

**my_graph_controllers**

```
@data = [
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
      ]
```

**view/my_graph.html.erb**

```
<head>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
</head>

<div class="container">

  <%= bar_chart @data, isStacked: true, isStacked: "percentage" %>

</div>
```

**assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require highcharts
```

**gemfile**

```
gem "chartkick"
```

Comment: Have you tried just `<%= bar_chart @data, stacked: true %>`?
Chartkick seems to have made some options 'native'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the trick is to transform the data a bit.

```
@data = [
      {
        name: "Fantasy & Sci Fi", 
        data: [["2010", 10], ["2020", 16], ["2030", 28]]
      },
      {
        name: "Romance", 
        data: [["2010", 24], ["2020", 22], ["2030", 19]]
      },
      {
        name: "Mystery/Crime", 
        data: [["2010", 20], ["2020", 23], ["2030", 29]]
      }
    ]
```

And this works like a charm then:

```
<%= bar_chart @data, stacked: true %>
```

I have found the answer in an older question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388877/3790990).

However, if you want to do the percentage stack, you need to use the **library** hash for that.

```
<%= bar_chart @data, adapter: 'google', library: { isStacked: 'percent' } %>
```

P.s. Notice that it should be either *true* or *'percent'* for the **isStacked**. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#StackedBars).

Comment: Many thanks. It works. I have one question more and one comment.
Question: do you know how to display it in % as the first imaged in my question? I tried with `<%= bar_chart @data, stacked: true, stacked: 'percentage %>
` with little success. Comment: fix your reply modifying `@test_data` as `@data´ or it does not work.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking I got this to work:
`<%= bar_chart @data, adapter: 'google', library: { isStacked: 'percent' } %>`

Comment: Many thanks, you are helping a lot! Last question, I am trying to rotate the graph (basically I want it vertical and not horizontal, as it is now) but I am not able to find the command on the documentation.

Comment: Then it's called a **column_chart** instead of a **bar_chart**. Everything else stays the same. :)